# is there a function or unit sames as TIniFiles that will not save to file?

Tags: delphi, ini, tinifile

I have a project that use Inifile for reading the data configuration.
I decided to save the configuration to the resource.

i would like to ask help if is there a Unit or function that same as Tinfile or related that saving the data config is optional.

any suggestions aside from extraction?

thanx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TMemIniFile is what you need and should always be preferred to TIniFile. You choose whether or not to save to file.

What you can't do directly is initialize it from a resource, but it's not too hard to put it together yourself.

1. Use a resource stream to extract your resource.
2. Create a string list and call load your resource stream into the string list.
3. Create a TMemIniFile and call SetStrings passing the string list.

Answer (score 8):

There is a class named TMemIniFile that only saves the changes to the inifile when you call `UpdateFile`. Is that good enough for you?

Answer (score 7):

TMemIniFile (descendant of TCustomIniFile) will not save unless you tell it to `UpdateFile;`